# Bare infinitive vs to-infinitive

Tags: infinitives, prepositional-phrases, complements, licensing, bare-infinitives

I found these sentences in my book:

> 1. He did nothing but **cry**.
> 2. He had no choice but **to obey**.

Example #1 uses a *bare infinitive* ("cry"), but example #2 uses a *to-infinitive* ("to obey").

Why is this so?

Comment: There might be related info in the 2002 *CGEL*,  in the section "(g) Matrix-licensed complements", on pages 641-3. It seems that the complements of the PPs in your two examples might be licensed by the matrix clause itself.

Answer (score 3):

I think we can understand this syntax in terms of the verb in the matrix clause:

He *did*...

He *had*...

These verbs govern the objects on either side of *but*.

He did nothing but he (did) cry.

He had no choice but he (had) to obey.

We cannot say "*he did to cry". Nor can we say "*he had obey".

Thus:

When he was rescued from the desert, the parched man *did* nothing but ________.

Comment: +1 But I suggest that the verb which governs *to obey* is not *have to* but *choose* -- derivative/cognate nouns often take the same sorts of complement as the verbs they're related to.

Comment: Yes I get your point. Actually in my book says bare infinitive is used with 'but, than, and ,except, as, or'. So i get confused with these sentences. Sometimes this rule follows sometimes not. for example: "to give is better than to receive". In you example there should be bare infinitive.

Comment: @starun008: "To give is better..." doesn't follow the same subject-transitiveverb-object-"but" pattern.

Comment: @StoneyB I don't get your point. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: @StoneyB: I'm on the fence about that.  *The battalion had no alternative but to retreat*.

Comment: @starun008 StoneyB's saying that the infinitive there has nothing to do with the verb *had* - for example we could have *we were given no choice but to leave* or *there was no choice but for us to leave*.

Comment: @stoney, Tromano, So to make that clear, it's the noun choice which has the infinitive as it's complement?

Comment: @Araucaria That's my gut feel: *having the choice to obey* "derives from" *choose to obey*. *He had [ no [choice] but [the choice to obey] ].*

Comment: @StoneyB Yes, I quite agree! :)

Comment: Now I am getting confuse again. You all are right. You all have your point to prove your rule. @Araucaria saying the infinitive has nothing to do with verb "had". It is contradicting the answer above answer than how to find what to use "bare infinitive" or "to + infinitive".

Comment: @Araucaria: What underlying verb governs in "...had no alternative but to retreat"?

Comment: @TRomano *I* didn't say that there was an underlying verb. There are different types of complement clauses that a word may take: *-ing*,  [for ...] *to*-infinitive, plain form, finite clause. But it seems that in those examples there is nothing special about the verb *HAVE* - (which isn't being used as part of a *have to* construction in the matrix clause anyhow). For the latest example, we might have "*there was no alternative but to retreat*". It doesn't seem like a good theory that the *to*-infinitive is because of *BE*. It seems to be because of something else ... It's interesting!  :-)

Comment: @starun008 It wasn't originally me! It was StoneyB (though I agree!)

Comment: @Araucaria What kind of infinitives do nouns take as complements? They can take to-infinitives, but can they also take bare-infinitives?

Comment: I'd be interested in the analysis of *Nero did little but fiddle* in light of this (to me new and strange) idea that nouns take complements.